# Alernative to printf("%*s",indent,message) in java?

Tags: java, printf, println

In C we can specify the amount to space to leave in printf , any similar way to do this in java?

For example

```
int space=6;
char message[10]="hi";

printf("%*s",space,message);
```

will print

```
    hi
```

Comment: AFAIK you'd have to dynamically build a sequence of whitespace for the indentation. You could create method yourself that mimicks that behavior, which shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: I know but i need to solve certain problems under constrains where writing too many methods etc aint allowed, I'ms urprised that C has this Out of the box and not java

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create the format string dynamically:

```
int space = 6;
System.out.printf("%" + space + "s", "hi");
```

Comment: `println` doesn't take a format string in Java. If you want the output in a `String`, use `String result = String.format("%" + space + "s", message);`

Comment: No. The first argument is the format string. It's not printed literally (if you use `printf`). (Try it out!). The format string does not need to be a string literal.

Comment: If you prefer to, you could also build the format string with format: `System.out.printf(String.format("%%%ds", space), "hi");`.

Comment: thanks a lot , now i understand clearly , but in c instead of (%5s...) we can use (%*s,...) and pass the formating value also as an argument , that is not possible in java 's System.out.printf.........right?

Comment: No, but it's not much harder to do the same thing in Java, as you can see.